# How to View the contents for Java Compiler

Tags: java

I want to know how exactly Java Compiler checks the syntax for Java programs. Can we actually view the content for Compiler which shows the rules pre-defined by JAVA

Comment: Do you mean the source code for `javac`? Check the [OpenJDK repos](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/). The source is also included in the `src.zip` file that comes with the JDK.

Comment: I mean you can browse the OpenJDK source, I think this should narrow it down: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/langtools/file/19293ea3999f/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac.  But this is a massive thing to look at, are you sure you're not looking for the *spec* of the Java language instead?  That's defined here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/index.html.  Either way I don't think this is a great fit since there's no clear answer, so going to vote to close and you can just take what you will from comments.

Comment: i just want to understand the rules that JAVAC follow for checking the syntax

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by "contents" of the compiler. If you want to understand how compilers work in general, check out a book on compiler theory.

If you specifically want to understand how a Java compiler works, you can browse the OpenJDK repo (I can't post a link right now so just google it). I should warn you though, it is a massive codebase, and you need to understand at least a bit of compiler theory to make sense of it.

If you just want to understand the rules that Java compilers need to follow, and aren't bothered with implementation, then read the Java Language Specification (and possibly the Java Virtual Machine Specification). These books are large and very technical, but are the best resources for understanding the rules of Java.

Comment: yes i want to understand the rules that Java Compiler follow. Do you have any recommendation for the same?